# Nested Table with fix col and thead row

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, jquery-ui

I want to create a Nested Table with fixed column and thead but i'm facing some challenge.

I can able to fix last column in first level but when try fix other column in nested level also it's not working properly.

Can someone help me what's the issue

I want to fix thead and last col of body in nested level also

Code is below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var viewRows = document.querySelectorAll(".main-table tbody tr.view");

        viewRows.forEach(function (row) {
          var firstColumn = row.querySelector("td:first-child");
          if (firstColumn) {
            firstColumn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
              var nestedRow = row.nextElementSibling;
              if (nestedRow && nestedRow.classList.contains("fold-child")) {
                nestedRow.classList.toggle("open");
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .table-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  
  .main-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;

  }
  thead {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 150px; /* Set your desired max-width */
    width: 150px;
  }
  
  .fixed-column {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .fold {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .fold-child {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .open {
    display: table-row;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
      <table class="main-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Estimate Name</th>
            <th>Total cost</th>
            <th>Code Library</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Asset Class</th>
            <th>Asset Type</th>
            <th>BUA m²</th>
            <th>GFA m²</th>
            <th>NIA m²</th>
            <th class="fixed-column">Total Estimate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="fold view">
            <td>0422</td>
            <td>
              Design and Archtitectural Supervsion Services, Ateliers Jean
              Nouvel: Luxury Resort
            </td>
            <td>24-Nov-2020</td>
            <td>NRM1codeLibrary(L1-L4) 2nd Edn</td>
            <td>Contract Bill of Quantities</td>
            <td>Sheraan Desert Resort</td>
            <td>Hospitality</td>
            <td>Hotel & Residences</td>
            <td>1100.00</td>
            <td>1100.00</td>
            <td>1100.00</td>
            <td class="fixed-column nested-content">19,599,749.01</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Add more rows and nested rows as needed -->
          <tr class="fold fold-child">
            <td colspan="12">
              <table class="nested-table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="fold view">
                    <td>0423</td>
                    <td>
                      Design and Archtitectural Supervsion Services, Ateliers
                      Jean Nouvel: Luxury Resort
                    </td>
                    <td>24-Nov-2020</td>
                    <td>NRM1codeLibrary(L1-L4) 2nd Edn</td>
                    <td>Contract Bill of Quantities</td>
                    <td>Sheraan Desert Resort</td>
                    <td>Hospitality</td>
                    <td>Hotel & Residences</td>
                    <td>1100.00</td>
                    <td>1100.00</td>
                    <td>1100.00</td>
                    <td class="fixed-column nested-content">19,599,749.01</td>
                    <!-- Nested row content goes here -->
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="fold fold-child">
                    <td colspan="12">
                      <table class="nested-table">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="fold view">
                            <td>0424</td>
                            <td>
                              Design and Archtitectural Supervsion Services,
                              Ateliers Jean Nouvel: Luxury Resort
                            </td>
                            <td>24-Nov-2020</td>
                            <td>NRM1codeLibrary(L1-L4) 2nd Edn</td>
                            <td>Contract Bill of Quantities</td>
                            <td>Sheraan Desert Resort</td>
                            <td>Hospitality</td>
                            <td>Hotel & Residences</td>
                            <td>1100.00</td>
                            <td>1100.00</td>
                            <td>1100.00</td>
                            <td class="fixed-column">
                              19,599,749.01
                            </td>
                            <!-- Nested row content goes here -->
                          </tr>
                          <!-- Add more nested rows as needed -->
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- Add more nested rows as needed -->
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question; please do not just send us to external platforms.

Comment: In what way is it not working? The code snippet you added is helpful, but we need to know what result you want and how the current code is working differently.

Comment: @ebbishop just click on the sr no (0422) and open the nested level see the impact in total estimate columns